# Replace String no matter uppercase and lowercase

Tags: java, regex, string

Well.. i got the values in a `ArrayList`...

How could do for "mark" the words that was getting  in a "Description" value?
f.e:

```
Criteria = car
matches founded... 2
Old Description value = My carbohidrates, .... is a team, i wanna go to park in the car

New Description value = My <font color='red'>car</font>bohidrates, .... is a team, i wanna go to park in the <font color='red'>Car</font>
```

The problem could solved with:

```
descriptionValue.replace(criteria, "<font color='red'>"+criteria+"</font>");
```

My problem begin when my criteria have uppercase or lowercase combinations... f.e:

```
Car, cAr, CaR....etc...
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: use the `/i` modifier

Comment: You can use (?ui)  for eg.. replaceAll("(?ui)car", "<font....>car</font>");

Answer (score 1):

Use a case-insensitice regular expression... `....replaceAll("(?i)car", "<font....>car</font>");`

Answer (score 0):

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
```

use regex with case insensitive matching try to replace it with your String

here are some links which you should visit which will set up all things clear in your mind
[Java Regular Expression](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

[Search and Replace](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/search_replace.shtml#.UnEDJxyw3T4)